# Standard library module not available on CI (occasionally)

Tags: elixir, circleci-2.0

`** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Base.hex_encode32/2 is undefined (module Base is not available)`

using elixir 1.8.2 and having the following error "randomly" in the test step on CI

Using circle CI with `circleci/elixir:1.8.2` and the error goes away if I rerun the whole build from start (including dependency installation) when rerunning only the test step it's consistently failing.

The `Base` Module is part of 1.8 Standard Library so I'm confused on whats going on.

Any hints on how to get rid of this are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Updating the project to latest elixir version (1.13.1) solved the random failures on CI.